# Why is this code need an index number on the front of the object?

Tags: java, arraylist

`ArrayList<AuctionItems> auction = new ArrayList<AuctionItems>();`

`auction.add("AdBoard",13000);` //When I write this, it says "java: incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to int", then I understand because it needs an index type in the front of the add object to array part. So I typed this:

`auction.add(0,"AdBoard",13000);`

Then this error message came out:
"java: no suitable method found for add(int,java.lang.String,int)
method java.util.ArrayList.add(AuctionItems) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method java.util.ArrayList.add(int,AuctionItems) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)"

So what's really the problem here?

Comment: Your list is declared to hold instances of `AuctionItems` so that is what `add` method is expecting as argument. Instead you are providing `String` and `int`. I am guessing you are under impression that Java will automatically create instance of `AuctionItems` from that data, but that is not true. You need to explicitly create it yourself like `auction.add(new AuctionItems("AdBoard",13000));` (assuming that there is such constructor in `AuctionItems` class).

Comment: If that was not what you ware trying to accomplish then please use [edit] option and clarify your question by including description of what you *want* this code to do.